# How can I execute a Bash program from C?

Tags: c, bash

How can I execute a command with bash? `system()` uses sh and not bash.

I know that I can execute commands in bash with `system("/bin/bash -c command")`.  But I have a very long command and `/bin/bash -c` gives me problems. What I need is `bashrun(command)` or something else.

The command is a string, not a file

Comment: Why not set the shebang in your bash script, than you don't have to worry what runs it because it will always be bash? `#!/bin/bash -f` at the top.

Comment: To ensure using Bash, you can use: `execve("/bin/bash", args_array, environ)` where `args_array[0] = "script.sh"` (you must manage memory for this properly) or similar. Have to be careful to get the correct environment in.

Comment: I believe this is not a duplicate - it is asking how to use bash instead of `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 4):

**Case1 : script from a file - Use the shebang**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

at the top of your script and then do

```
int status=system("/full/path/to/script");
if(status==-1){
// failure mode
}
```

**Case2 : script stored as a string**

Do something like below

```
char *command="$(which bash) -c 'ls'";
int status=system(command);
if (status==-1){
  //failure mode
}
```

Comment: That shebang is wrong. It should be `#!/bin/bash`, and even then the norm is to use `env`: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` unless you have a very specific reason as `env` cannot pass arguments to the interpreter.

Comment: @Tatsh : Thanks for the pointer. I just noted that. Also regarding `/usr/bin/env bash` excellent suggestion. Incorporated :)

Comment: @Tatsh Using `env` is certainly not a *norm*. Some prefer it while others don't. `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will use whatever it finds first in the PATH (a potential security issue). SO, it's not necessarily better than plain `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I want to execute a string, not a script

Comment: @Wilma456  : See the  update.

Comment: @P.P. : See your point. If a user account has been compromised, a bad guy could modify the `PATH` variable. Having said that many( I guess) linux admins advocate the use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` for portability reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a very long shell command and you need bash to interpret it, then you have two real options:

1. Save the text into a file and invoke bash with the filename as a single argument (equivalently, use a shebang in the file to specify bash as the interpreter, make the file executable, and invoke that as command), or
2. Start an instance of bash with `popen()` and write the shell command as standard input to the bash process.

If you're having problems due to shell script quoting (rather than the command length), then either of those options would work, or you could implement the equivalent of `system()` but using `execl()` to pass the argument without going through `sh`.  I'm assuming a POSIX-type system here.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int run_bash(const char *command)
{
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        /* failed */
        perror("fork");
        return pid;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", command, (char*)NULL);
        perror("exec");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        /* parent */
        int status;
        do {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status));
        return WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    run_bash("echo '*'");
}
```